# Wordpress NextGen Gallery Lightbox not working on Live Server

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I've just built my first Wordpress site locally and have transferred it to a subdomain for testing purposes. One thing that doesn't work on the live server but does locally is the NextGen image gallery.

http://connorhome.com/moorfield/accommodation/

The gallery shows and loads all the photos, but the lightbox feature isn't working, instead it just opens the image in the same tab. The desired effect that occurs locally is pictured below:

[image]

When inspecting the two sites, you can see there are classes missing ('.shutterset_set_2') from the live site. Here is a screenshot of the inspector on the local site which works fine:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is no longer working on live? There are no console errors. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure (the plugin’s) JavaScript is executed on your live site?

Comment: I'm guessing it isn't doing, but the JS files are linked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the 'shutter' effect in the NextGen Gallery Options wasn't selected, I assumed this would have been a setting which would have been saved in the local DB and exported over but apparently not.